# exception upload more than 500 bytes to app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I hava a problem upload more than 500 bytes to app engine. The system throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: video: byte[] properties must be 500 bytes or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob, which can store binary data of any size.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:259)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:208)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:149)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyContainer.setProperty(PropertyContainer.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.setEntityProperty(EntityUtils.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeFieldInEntity(StoreFieldManager.java:360)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeObjectField(StoreFieldManager.java:190)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.providedObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:1447)
    at com.rmi.videoservice.PersistentVideo.jdoProvideField(PersistentVideo.java)
    at com.rmi.videoservice.PersistentVideo.jdoProvideFields(PersistentVideo.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.provideFields(AbstractStateManager.java:1515)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2357)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1896)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1745)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
    at com.rmi.videoservice.Upload.doPost(Upload.java:33)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:484)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
```

This error appears in the doPost method, it avoids the correct storage of data.
Someone suggest me a solution about?

Comment: It is actually giving you a suggestion there: `byte[] properties must be 500 bytes or less. Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob, which can store binary data of any size.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datastore is not designed to store a lot of data. The entity size limit is 1M, and `byte[]` fields are limited to a size of 500KB.

If you need to store bigger data, as RealSkeptic mentioned in his comment, you can use the Blobstore ([documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/)).

I personnally consider Google Cloud Storage ([documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/)) a better alternative, it has more features and seems like it gets more attention from the Google team lately.

You should compare both options and choose which one is best for you. Note that you will need to modify your code logic as both the Blobstore and Cloud Storage have specific upload methods.

Comment: Thanks David. You comment help me.